# How to get remove some string out of a larger string in JavaScript, when I don't know their positions

Tags: javascript, string, indexing

I have this text:

```
Blah Blah Blah SPECIAL TEXT: PART OF IT
blah bah SPECIAL TEXT: STILL PART OF IT
blah blah blah blah
```

How do I use JavaScript to get this result:

```
Blah Blah Blah
blah bah
blah blah blah blah
```

How do I remove the text in capital letters.

Note that the part after the ":" and before the line break is not meant to be in capital, but it's part of the text that has to go, so I can't just say remove all text in capital.

Also note that I do not know exactly where the text to be removed will start and end, what I do know is that it starts when there is an occurrence of several consecutive capital letters typed side by side and ends when there is a line break.

I've tried getting the index of the first few capital letters by just using `search("SPECIAL")`, and getting the end by using `search("\n")`. The issue with this is getting the line break after the "SPECIAL TEXT" and no other.

So finally, if I do get the positions, both starting and ending, I guess I could just get whatever string is in between the two indexes, and replace them with an empty string and iterate the process.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `split(/regex/)`

Comment: Before I answer your question, tell me: You want to remove from `SPECIAL TEXT:` to `EOL` (end of line) right?

Comment: Yeah and not loose other text after end of line

Comment: And: Is `SPECIAL TEXT:` string `"SPECIAL TEXT:"` or a class of strings with special form (e.g. all-uppercase-letter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: Its string "SPECIAL TEXT"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this regular expression?

```
("Blah Blah Blah SPECIAL TEXT: PART OF IT\n" +
"blah bah SPECIAL TEXT: STILL PART OF IT\n" +
"blah blah blah blah").replace(/SPECIAL\sTEXT:.+$/mg,'')
```

This basically means replace any string fragments starting with `SPECIAL TEXT:` followed by some characters (`.+`) and ending with end of line (`$`). Examine all lines individually instead of whole string at once (`m`) and don't stop after the first one replacement (`g`)

Comment: `replace()` replaces only one substring. But there're two

Comment: I really, love your approach. Straightforward and ridiculously simple. Thanks. I've been hitting my head for a while.

Comment: What kind of markup? There isn't any in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Try a regex:

```js
var str = "Blah Blah Blah SPECIAL TEXT: PART OF IT\nblah bah SPECIAL TEXT: STILL PART OF IT\nblah blah blah blah"
console.log(str.replace(/SPECIAL.*$/gm, ''))
/*
Blah Blah Blah
blah bah
blah blah blah blah
*/
```

`SPECIAL`: match “SPECIAL”
`.*`: match anything but `\n` (newline)
`$`: match the end of the line
`/g`: match multiple times
`/m`: match `$` on the end of each line, not just the end of the string
`''`: replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "Blah Blah Blah SPECIAL TEXT: PART OF IT\n blah bah SPECIAL TEXT: STILL PART OF IT\n blah blah blah blah"

var arr = text.split("\n");

var newArray = arr.map(function(item){
  if(item.indexOf("SPECIAL TEXT") !== -1){
    return item.substring(0, item.indexOf("SPECIAL TEXT"));
   } else {
     return item
     }
});

text = newArray.join("\n");

alert(text);
```

Comment: What of the other part? It'll get lost

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    var text = 'Blah Blah Blah SPECIAL TEXT: PART OF IT blah bah SPECIAL TEXT: STILL PART OF IT blah blah blah blah';  //save the text in a variable 

    var arr = text.split(" ")  /// make array with the words from the text

    arr = arr.filter(e => e=='Blah' || e=='blah') // filter the words

    arr = arr.join(' ')  // convert the array back to a string

Output: 'Blah Blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah'
```

Comment: Great, but it looses the line breaks

Comment: Hmm, I can implement and method that once the element is not equal with the string to break the line, reduce should be a better method in that case